android studio emulator not running
i had updated my android studio to the latest version and from that time my emulator is not working it is showing the error The emulator process for AVD Pixel_9_Pro_XL_API_34 has terminated. my other emulator is working fine pixel 5 api 28 the only problem is pixel 8 and 9 with api 33 and api 34 please help
i tried all the ways on internet that can solve this but still it is not working reinstall the emulator update still not working i tried chat gpt with log and this the answer it gave me Vulkan Hardware GPU Error: The error vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties: Invalid physicalDevice    Quickboot Choice Error: The warning Failed to process .ini file             please help
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Increasing RAM size to 3072MB
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - IPv4 server found: 192.168.55.230
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: f0ac:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: f0ac:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: f0ac:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: 50b5:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: 50b5:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: 50b5:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: 68bb:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: 68bb:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: 68bb:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: d8cd:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: d8cd:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: d8cd:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: f8d3:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: f8d3:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Ignore IPv6 address: f8d3:b51d:d001:0:30a7:b51d:d001:0
2024-10-19 21:29:50,735 [ 430829]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\Arsalan.android\avd..\avd\Pixel_9_Pro_XL_API_34.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Critical:
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Warning:
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Warning:
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Warning:
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Warning:
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Warning:
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Warning:
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Warning:
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Arsalan\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-35.2.10.db, detection is enabled for process: 7360
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - library_mode host gpu mode host
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - emuglConfig_get_vulkan_hardware_gpu: Failed to query physical devices 5
2024-10-19 21:29:55,851 [ 435945]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 -
2024-10-19 21:29:55,899 [ 435993]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - ERROR:             vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties: Invalid physicalDevice [VUID-vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties-physicalDevice-parameter]
2024-10-19 21:30:00,328 [ 440422]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
2024-10-19 21:30:00,328 [ 440422]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 9 Pro XL API 34 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073740791
2024-10-19 21:30:00,643 [ 440737]   WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_9_Pro_XL_API_34 has terminated.

It seems like it's a Vulkan API issue.
Vulkan API aims to render through hardware acceleration.
Have you tried these steps? :
Configure Hardware Acceleration:
-

Opening the AVD Manager
Creating a new AVD or editing your Pixel_9_Pro_XL_API_34
Finding the Emulated Performance section in the Verify
Configuration window
Selecting a value for the Graphics: option
Clicking Finish


This isn‘t an answer. Please use the comment section if you want to ask for further information.

did you meant all the log entries ?? with error

@ArsalanShaikh Yes is what I am referring to, thanks.

After trying several alternatives, I managed to solve my problem just by updating the video card driver, after that the driver updated the dll "vulkan-1.dll" which is located in "C:\Windows\System32" and the emulator finally returned to function correctly.
